# ADOMD nuget package for asp.net core

Tags: ssas, asp.net-core-2.0, nuget-package, cube, adomd.net

I am looking at [ADOMD nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.retail.amd64/). It seems it does not support ASP.NET Core framework. How can I Get this nuget package for ASP.NET core. If not this package, do we have any other alternative to connect to cube ?

Answer (score 4):

There are no official .NET Core-compatible ADOMD.NET yet:

- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20809
- https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35508349-adomd-core

You can try [this unofficial port of "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientNetCore/).

If your hosting environment is windows, you can create simple .NET Framework-based microservice that handles requests to SSAS from your main ASP.NET Core app.

--- update ---

One more alternative: [XMLA client](https://github.com/RadarSoft/xmla-client) that is compatible with .NET Core 2

Comment: can you add the link to the unofficial port of "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient".

Answer (score 2):

ADOMD.NET (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient) for .NET Core is [available](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64/) in preview on nuget now. This is an official Microsoft maintained library.

Edit: Apparently it now also works for on-prem Analysis Services in addition to Azure Analysis Services and Power BI Premium.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Any tentative date for drivers availability for on-prem cubes ?

Comment: It works with on-prem cubes as well (using win auth). I haven't noticed any issues.

Comment: @AlexBar thanks for reporting. I’ve updated the answer to reflect this.