# How can I query data in an Azure Analysis Service from a ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-analysis-services

I have an cloud application that dumps all its data into an `Azure Data Lake`.

Using `Azure Data Factory`, I have built a pipeline that extracts and transforms the data from the lake and saves it in local `.csv` files.

These `.csv` files are accessible in an `Azure SQL Data Warehouse` as external files that are CTAS as proper SQL tables.

I have created an `Azure Analysis Service` instance that is hooked up to the warehouse, provides additionnal information out of the existing data and caches it.

**Question**

I want to make this data available from a Web API. I have created a `ASP.NET Core application` and I would like this application to connect the service to query the data.

Knowing that the client libraries ([ADOMD](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.retail.amd64/15.15.0)) are all .NET Framework libraries that can't loaded in a .NET Core app, how should I do this?

Comment: Are you using the Azure Data Warehouse in an OLTP design (i.e. the backend of an application) or an OLAP design (i.e. for analytics processing, using a dimensional model of some sort)?
It seems somewhat counterintuitive to use a web API to access a data analytics services, which is generally used to serve data to Power BI or Excel or other analytics tool.

Comment: The WebAPI would be used to feed charts on a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now an official version of ADOMD.NET for .NET Core available. See [another answer here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62470657/5070440).

Answer (score 1):

There are no official .NET Core-compatible ADOMD.NET yet:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20809

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35508349-adomd-core

You can try this unofficial port of "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient".

If your hosting environment is windows, you can create simple .NET Framework-based microservice that handles requests to SSAS from your main ASP.NET Core app

Answer (score 0):

I tried the "Unofficial.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient" for getting data out of the cube via REST Api. It worked really well and the response time is great. I am just not confident that more advanced stuf (partition management. . .) will work with this package, since it does not seem to be developed regularly.